# How do I add PDF files in Voyager?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I try to add PDF from the admin panel, but I get a message saying that it is added and get this page right after

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably have a route like `/storage/{model}` but your URL says `/storage/[]`, so a `NotFoundHttpException` is thrown because it can't resolve `[]` as `{model}`

Comment: Please translate the title. I suggest "How do I add PDF files in Voyager?".

Comment: if you dont mind how can i fix it ?